# Automatic form submission with PERL - debugging!

Tags: html, perl

Our client has a simple setup.

Page A has a form that submits to page B which displays the query results. Unfortunately, there is no other API or DB access to get the data.

Since we need to do this query often, we decided to automate this submission with Perl.

I've determined the form key value pairs of Page A with a sniffer and replicated the code. However, on running the program page B is throwing a HTTP 500 error with no additional meaningful explanation.

Any pointers to debug this code? Code in itself is simple:

```
use strict;
  use warnings;
  use LWP;
  my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;

  my $url = "targeturl.asp"
  my $response = $browser->post( $url,
    [
    "HisSort" => "1", 
    "RTsort" => "", 
    "chkHisRun" => "on", 
    "chkRTRun" => "on", 
    "optAdHoc" => "on", 
    "optHist" => "", 
    "optServer" => "servername", 
    "optStatus" => "", 
    "optWhat" => "H", 
    "txtEnd" => "", 
    "txtFields" => "1,0,10,17,11,18,24,19,21,25,1", 
    "txtHEnd" => "11/3/2010", 
    "txtHStart" => "11/1/2010", 
    "txtServer" => "", 
    "txtStart" => "",
    ]
  );
```

Note:
I don't have access to the source of page A or page B

Comment: You should probably provide a full URL.

Comment: If you were sending an identical request, you would get an identical response. Therefore you need to find out where your request is different from the browser's. Are there cookies, for example? Your Perl script doesn't seem to try and set any headers to match the browsers, either - perhaps page B is failing to parse the User-Agent, say.

Comment: Also it can be UserAgent string ($browser->agent("...")) or some cookie received earlier...

Comment: Benoit - it is an intranet URL and was obfuscated when posting here. No issues there.

Comment: It's called Perl, not PERL: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team,
This has been resolved. 
It eventually turned out that the problem was not with the headers but with the key value pairs I was sending. Page B wasn't doing validations on the fields and was plugging them into a query directly.

I had to try some brute force combinations (by testing with Page A) to get to what exactly page B was expecting.

Thanks to all who volunteered to help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suggest looking at [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) which is a friendlier wrapper around LWP. Secondly, if your HTTP client is getting 500 errors, then there should be something more meaningful in the web server error logs. And finally, as Matthew has mentioned, you need to closely examine the request being sent by the browser and work out how it differs from the request that your Perl program is sending.

Comment: Matthew / Davorg - thanks for your inputs. I am constrained by what I can install on the server, but I will see if Mechanize is already there. I am sort of blindfolded in understanding what B is expecting. Is there anyway I can put something in between A and B to see the headers of A's output? All sniffer pages I have encountered seem to take a web page and display its headers and under the circumstances that doesn't help me much.

Comment: Can you install Wireshark anywhere to snoop the traffic to B?